# GDB print backtrace instead of breaking when watching an address

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

In GDB I'd like to `watch` a memory address being written to. However, is it possible to set the `watch` so when the address is written-to, instead of breaking to the command line we print the backtrace and continue execution?

Comment: Add [`commands`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html) for the watchpoint, containing `continue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first set a watch to the given variable:

```
(gdb) watch i
```

Now in the list of breakpoints you will see the watch. E.g.:

```
(gdb) info breakpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       hw watchpoint  keep y                      i
```

At this point you can define a [breakpoint command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands) to be executed at any breakpoint or watch point. In your case, you just want to execute "backtrace" and "c". To define this, enter `commands 1`, and then the list of commands to be executed whenever the watchpoint is hit. E.g.:

```
(gdb) commands 1
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>backtrace
>c
>end
```

The "1" after "commands" refers to the watchpoint number that you can see in the "info breakpoints" output.